# Compile Processing from command line with added library

Tags: java, processing

I tried compile p5 using command line these days.

I don't know much about command line compile.

Though it took me long time to do it, I succeeded.

I use javac command like below:

```
javac -d $PATH_TO_BIN -classpath $PATH_TO_JAR: $file_name
```

But I couldn't use added libraries, such as controlP5.

I want to know how to compile by command line with added libraries.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to run from the command line you will need to add the controlP5 library / .jar file as you would with any other java .jar based library by appending it to the classpath when you call javac.